# Repeat a range of values starting at a specifc value without using vba

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Using only the formula's provided by excel what i want to do is create a repeating list of values starting from a inputted value that exists in the range.

for example:

[image]

In this example I have a list of 4 names, and when someone enters one of the names in the input box in D1 a list of repeating values will appear in the D column starting with "Bob".

I'm not that skilled in using Excel formula's so I'm wondering if this is even possible without using vba

Answer (score 2):

In D2, use:

```
=IF(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(D1,A:A,0)+1)="",A$2,INDEX(A:A,MATCH(D1,A:A,0)+1))
```

Then copy down.

[image]

Comment: I'm getting #N/A in all the rows

Comment: I added a screenshot showing results and the formula in D2. Make certain the ranges such as the input being in D1 and the data in column A matches or adjust the formula to match.

Comment: josh is part of the list of names, that kinda why i used bob as the example to exorcise the point that i would like to be able to start in the middle of the list and start right back up at the top of the list

Comment: Oops. Misunderstood the question. Edited answer.